# Standards source where VCF TYPE=pref is defined (as the preferred of a medium)?

Tags: contacts, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm currently building a contacts module and thus the first task is a contacts import function. I've noticed the string `TYPE=pref` seems to occur only once per medium (e.g. email, telephone, URL). It seems intuitive that this infers a *preferred* instance of a medium (e.g. call their cell phone instead of their office number).

Where can I find confirmation of this specific string in the VCF standard? Alternatively since I'm aware of the mess that the VCF format seems to come in (my export will generate a completely clean/consistent new file) if this is something specific to Android in example I would be happy to see that documentation instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification there is a dedicated field called 'PREF' which stands for *preferred*: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-5.3

It would make sense `TYPE=pref` has that same reasoning.

Comment: It's a bit late though I'll up-vote it for now. Eventually I'll revisit the code I worked on though.